# AppScript fails to execute when automated using AppScript Dashboard

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am running a script that takes the latest sheet and duplicates it. I want to run this every Tuesday and Friday. I have setup the script to trigger automatically using the App Script Dashboard. However, the script fails with the error "Please select an active sheet first"

If I run the code when from the script, it works fine. I am guessing this is because the file is open and the active sheet is the one I have selected.

This is my code:

```
function createNewSheet() {

  //Calcualte tomorrow's date
  var today = new Date();
  var tomo = new Date();
  tomo.setDate(today.getDate()+1);
  var SheetName = tomo.toLocaleDateString();
  Logger.log(SheetName);

  //Duplicate sheet and set the name to tommorrow's date
  activeSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  Logger.log(activeSheet.getName());
  activeSheet.duplicateActiveSheet();
  newactiveSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
  newactiveSheet.setName(SheetName);

}
```

I was wondering what I need to change in my code to make sure the automation can work without errors.

Comment: Your guess is spot on. `activeSheet` in your code is merely the name of the spreadsheet. You need something like `var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();`[Google Doc](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#getactivesheet)

Comment: But then I get an error that `Cannot find function duplicateActiveSheet in object Sheet`

Edit: I have modified the code to now read
``` activeSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
  Logger.log(activeSheet.getName());
  
  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().duplicateActiveSheet();

Comment: OK. Let's troubleshoot. Question: if you run your script as-is, do you expect it to fail? If yes, then please run your script, then view the Execution transcript, copy the transcript (in full) and edit your question to include the transcript.

Comment: Does the code run with that edit?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't reply before. Yes the code executes with the edit - but it always duplicates the first Sheet. I wanted it to duplicate the latest sheet. I eventually gave up and did not try anything after this.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try the below code?

```
function createNewSheet() {

  //Calcualte tomorrow's date
  var today = new Date();
  var tomo = new Date();
  var yesterday = new Date();
  yesterday.setDate(today.getDate()-1);
  tomo.setDate(today.getDate()+1);
  var SheetName = tomo.toLocaleDateString();
  Logger.log(SheetName);

  //Duplicate sheet and set the name to tommorrow's date
  activeSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(yesterday).activate();
  Logger.log(activeSheet.getName());
  activeSheet.duplicateActiveSheet();
  newactiveSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
  newactiveSheet.setName(SheetName);
}
```